# How can I write the following code in a more efficient way in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, code-cleanup

From a file I have parsed the fields that I need and stored them in variables and it looks something like below:

```
field_list = ['some_value','some_other_value']
raw_data = """sring1|0|2|N.S.|3|
sring2|0|2|N.S.|2|
sring3|0|2|3|5|"""
```

Now I need to create a df which looks like:

```
      Str           Measure   Value
0  sring1        some_value  N.S.
1  sring1  some_other_value     3
2  sring2        some_value  N.S.
3  sring2  some_other_value     2
4  sring3        some_value     3
5  sring3  some_other_value     5
```

The logic here is as following:

E.g. For the line in **raw_data** "sring1|0|2|N.S.|3|" the **Str** Column  value would be *sring1* and the value for **Measure** Column will be *some_value*(which is coming from the **field_list**)  and the value for **Value** Column will be *N.S*

Now, again for the same string the value for the **Str** Column  value would be *sring1* and the value for **Measure** Column will be *some_other_value* and the value for **Value** Column will be *3*.

The |2| in the string "sring1|0|2|N.S.|3|" tells us how many rows will be there and the last two are the values for the **field_list**

Currently I have the following code:

```
field_list = ['some_value','some_other_value']

db_columns = ['Str','Measure','Value']

raw_data = """sring1|0|2|N.S.|3|
sring2|0|2|N.S.|2|
sring3|0|2|3|5|"""

entry_list = raw_data.splitlines()
final_db_list =[]
for entries in entry_list:
    each_entry_list = entries.split('|')
    security = each_entry_list[0].strip()
    print(each_entry_list)
    no_of_fields = int(each_entry_list[2])
    db_list=[]
    upload_list=[]
    for i in range (0,no_of_fields):
        field = field_list[i]
        value = each_entry_list[3+i]
        db_list=[security,field,value]
        upload_list.append(db_list)
    final_db_list.append(upload_list)
flatList = [ item for elem in final_db_list for item in elem]

df = DataFrame(flatList,columns=db_columns)
print(df)
```

Can someone please help me with a better way of doing this. The one that I have works but is too messy. Need to pythonize it a bit and I am out of ideas.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

We can do it like this:

```
import pandas as  pd
from io import StringIO

field_list = ['some_value','some_other_value']
raw_data = """sring1|0|2|N.S.|3|
sring2|0|2|N.S.|2|
sring3|0|2|3|5|"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data), sep='|', header=None)

df = df.drop(5, axis=1)

df = (df.set_index([0,1,2])
        .set_axis(field_list, axis=1)
        .reset_index(level=[1,2], drop=True)
        .stack()
        .rename('Value')
        .rename_axis(['Str', 'Measure'])
        .reset_index()
      )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Str           Measure Value
0  sring1        some_value  N.S.
1  sring1  some_other_value     3
2  sring2        some_value  N.S.
3  sring2  some_other_value     2
4  sring3        some_value     3
5  sring3  some_other_value     5
```